# Lookup Table, using AND in Lookup to get one result back

Tags: sql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I've been googling this for an hour or so and can only find 2 table answers.

```
Table1 - (ID uniqueidentifier PK)
Table2 - (ID uniqueidentifier PK, uniqueidentifier Table1ID, uniqueidentifier Table3ID)
Table3 - (ID uniqueidentifier PK, varchar(5) Code)
```

Table2 has a many to one relationship with both Table1 and Table 3

So sample data would be something like

```
Table1 (1)
Table2 (1, 1, 1)
Table2 (2, 1, 2)
Table2 (3, 1, 3)
Table3 (1, 'ABC')
Table3 (2, "DEF')
Table3 (3, "GHI')
```

I'm wanting to only get 1 result back from Table1 looking up Codes on Table3.

```
Example1: If I searched 'ABC' AND 'GHI', I would only get 1 result back
Example2: 'DEF' and "JKL' would not return a result since 'JKL' isn't linked in Table2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic set-within-sets question.  I like to solve these using `group by` and `having`, because that is the most flexible solution.  From what I can see `table1` is not actually needed for this:

```
select t2.Table1Id
from table2 t2 join
     table3 t3
     on t2.Table3ID = t3.Id
group by t2.table1Id
having sum(case when t3.code = 'ABC' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when t3.code = 'GHI' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

The reason I like this solution is because it is quite flexible.  If you wanted ABC but not GHI, you would use:

```
having sum(case when t3.code = 'ABC' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when t3.code = 'GHI' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

If you wanted XYZ as well as the other two:

```
having sum(case when t3.code = 'ABC' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when t3.code = 'GHI' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when t3.code = 'XYZ' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Comment: Well, I simplified it, Table1 is the main table I'm querying against and I wouldn't return anything back from Table2 or Table3 since this is just a filtering type of query.  Set within Set, that's what I was looking for, I knew there was some DB term for that.